# Flavored Butter Sauce/Liquid

Tags: sauce, oil, butter, garlic, griddle

To explain kind of what I am looking for. When going to a local Chinese restaurant they have a Mongolian bar where they cook the food you choose in flavored sauces of your choice. My go to is the butter garlic sauce. It is liquid & looks like oil & just in pans that don’t seem to be heated( at least that I can tell). But I am wanting to make some different flavored butters to keep in squeeze bottles for when using my griddle. I know there is no way to keep butter in a liquid. I would love to experiment with different flavor ideas, but definitely want a butter garlic flavor. Does anyone have any ideas or know of anywhere to order something like this? I wish there was a true butter flavored oil(not the spray butter) that I could just add different flavoring to.

Comment: One of the decent vegan butter substitutes (as distinct from margarine - they usually cost more, and taste better) would probably serve (don't use the "light" ones, they are half water.) Unrefrigerated, they return to oil...

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds to me like they're using clarified butter, or ghee.  It's butter with the milk solids removed which gives it the consistency of oil.  Not at all hard to do, just heat the butter to a low simmer and continually skim it until all of the milk solids are removed.  You can buy it already clarified, but I find that just doesn't taste as good.  Keeps for 6 months or so in the fridge.

[How to Clarify Butter](https://www.seriouseats.com/clarified-butter-recipe#:%7E:text=Once%20boiling%20has%20stopped%2C%20pour,6%20months%20in%20the%20refrigerator.)

Answer (score 1):

[Butter flavored olive oil](https://shop.benessereoil.com/Butter-375ml-infused-butter-375ml.htm) would be a good option for you.  I've bought the brand I linked to, and it has a very convincing butter flavor.